# How to process sabre InstaFlight API JSON response

Tags: json, vb.net, sabre

I connected to saber InstaFlight API and got a result in JSON. The output string is too long and I can get their values. But my way is taking lots of memory storage. I want a way that takes less memory storage and a dynamic way in VB.NET.

The code below is working fine with no error:

```
response2 = DirectCast(postReq.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
reader2 = New StreamReader(response2.GetResponseStream())
postReq.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
Dim ser1 As JObject = JObject.Parse(reader2.ReadToEnd())
```

I can get the values like this, with no error:

```
ElapseTime1 = ser1("PricedItineraries")(0)("AirItinerary")("OriginDestinationOptions")("OriginDestinationOption")(0)("ElapsedTime").Value(Of String)()
```

However, it gets to a point that you need hundreds of variables and this is not the right way.

An example of the output JSON:

> { "PricedItineraries": [ { "AirItinerary": { "OriginDestinationOptions": { "OriginDestinationOption": [ { "FlightSegment": [ { "DepartureAirport": { "LocationCode": "JFK" }, "ArrivalAirport": { "LocationCode": "LAS" }, "MarketingAirline": { "Code": "AS" }, "ArrivalTimeZone": { "GMTOffset": -7 }, "TPA_Extensions": { "eTicket": { "Ind": true } }, "StopQuantity": 0, "ElapsedTime": 344, "ResBookDesigCode": "R", "MarriageGrp": "O", "Equipment": { "AirEquipType": 320 }, "DepartureDateTime": "2017-07-07T09:30:00", "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-07-07T12:14:00", "FlightNumber": 1251, "OnTimePerformance": { "Percentage": 70 }, "OperatingAirline": { "CompanyShortName": "VIRGIN AMERICA", "FlightNumber": 251, "Code": "VX" }, "DepartureTimeZone": { "GMTOffset": -4 } }, { "DepartureAirport": { "LocationCode": "LAS" }, "ArrivalAirport": { "LocationCode": "LAX" }, "MarketingAirline": { "Code": "AS" }, "ArrivalTimeZone": { "GMTOffset": -7 }, "TPA_Extensions": { "eTicket": { "Ind": true } }, "StopQuantity": 0, "ElapsedTime": 85, "ResBookDesigCode": "R", "MarriageGrp": "O", "Equipment": { "AirEquipType": 320 }, "DepartureDateTime": "2017-07-07T14:45:00", "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-07-07T16:10:00", "FlightNumber": 1475, "OnTimePerformance": { "Percentage": 36 }, "OperatingAirline": { "CompanyShortName": "VIRGIN AMERICA", "FlightNumber": 475, "Code": "VX" }, "DepartureTimeZone": { "GMTOffset": -7 } } ], "ElapsedTime": 580 }, { "FlightSegment": [ { "DepartureAirport": { "LocationCode": "LAX" }, "ArrivalAirport": { "LocationCode": "LAS" }, "MarketingAirline": { "Code": "AS" }, "ArrivalTimeZone": { "GMTOffset": -7 }, "TPA_Extensions": { "eTicket": { "Ind": true } }, "StopQuantity": 0, "ElapsedTime": 71, "ResBookDesigCode": "R", "MarriageGrp": "O", "Equipment": { "AirEquipType": 320 }, "DepartureDateTime": "2017-07-08T17:00:00", "ArrivalDateTime": "2017-07-08T18:11:00", "FlightNumber": 1480, "OnTimePerformance": { "Percentage": 55 }, "OperatingAirline": { "CompanyShortName": "VIRGIN AMERICA", "FlightNumber": 480, "Code": "VX" }, "DepartureTimeZone": { "GMTOffset": -7 } }, { "DepartureAirport": { "LocationCode": "LAS" }, "ArrivalAirport": { "LocationCode": "JFK" }, "MarketingAirline": { "Code": "AS" }, "ArrivalTimeZone": { "GMTOffset": -4 }, "TPA_Extensions": { "eTicket": { "Ind": true } }, "StopQuantity": 0,

Comment: You should consider condensing your JSON for the question. Please see how to create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a model for this result. According to this JSON, you have to create a class model.

If you have this JSON:

```
{
"dailyDealId": "432",
"discountPercentage": "0",
"product": {
    "productId": "10",
    "brandId": "10",
    "departmentId": "3",
    "name": "Baby Girl Velour Tunic & Snowflake Legging Set",
    "description": "The pretty set",
    "url": "http://whatever.whatever.com/files/whatever.tif"
}
```

You need this model:

```
public class Product
{
    public string productId { get; set; }
    public string brandId { get; set; }
    public string departmentId { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string url { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string dailyDealId { get; set; }
    public string discountPercentage { get; set; }
    public Product product { get; set; }
}
```